# Url rewriting in php using .htaccess with more than two GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, getparameter

My URL is :

```
 http://example.com/demo/my_list.php?id=122&name=test files
```

Wan't to change this into:

```
 http://example.com/demo/my_list.php/test files/122
```

Currently My htaccess is as followes,

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ my_list.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

but its not working...

How to rewrite url in php with more than two GET variables?

Where I placed my htaccess file? inside the 'demo' folder or in root path?

Please any one help...

Comment: that url with space is not valid are you manually writing the URL ?!

Comment: not mannually, it's from db..

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this,

```
RewriteRule ^my_list\.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ my_list.php?id=$2&name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: sorry, not working, is the .htaccess file is placed inside the demo folder or in root folder?

Comment: use it in demo.

Comment: Yes i placed htaccess file in demo folder, but its not working

Comment: Try now without rewrite conditions.